# mount a drive in freeBSD to edit a file, using live CD

Tags: mount, livecd

I am trying to edit /boot/loader.conf in a freeBSD. The system was unable to boot because of some errors made to the file.

To rectify removing this errors i have to boot using live CD, mount the /boot partition,edit the file and write the changes. How could i know to locate what to mount , where to mount it and how to get into that slice of drive for editing?

Comment: Is it zfs or ufs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer .
Just to let you know, even using an ubuntu live CD, might just not do it.
I have used [this useful link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85154/mount-ufs-filesystem) :

```
# sudo modprobe ufs
# mkdir ~/ufs_mount
# sudo mount -r -t ufs -o ufstype=ufs2 /dev/sdb1 /home/<your_username>/ufs_mount
```

as home directory name.
sdb1 the drive desired to get into..

However you cannot write into a file in there.
Using -wr instead of -r wont work, you will get an error instead. [This should shed more light on that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24589/mounting-ufs-partition-with-read-write-permissions-on-ubuntu-10-04)

Now using the live installation disk (or usb) of freeBSD system, will work as follows:
after getting into the live CD make the following

```
# gpart show -l
```

you will see many slices, you will recognize the disk of the form adaN, N integer with slices of their indicated volumes, by going to /dev do -ls you will see names of slices , in my case among them was : ada0p2 which is the drive i need to get into.

, go to /tmp makdir there , name it ufs_mount. elsewhere mkdir won't work because you are in live CD and most of the folders are read only.
After that:

```
mount -wr -t ufs  /dev/ada0p2 /tmp/ufs_mount
```

ada0p2 is the name of the drive in my case.
Use Vi to edit your file, use cat to verify it and you are done.

Comment: I have tried this to no avail. For the mount to work you have to use the whole path: `/sbin/mount`. Learned the hard way...

Answer (score 0):

If the boot disk is using UFS. You might be able to get away with using `Escape to the loader prompt` (3) from the boot menu and

```
unload
load kernel
boot
```

Then fix `/boot/loader.conf` and reboot.

---

For ZFS, I believe you will need to boot the system from usb or cd. [mfsbsd](http://mfsbsd.vx.sk/) will do.

zpool import
   zpool import -o altroot=/mnt {root_zpool_name}

Edit `/mnt/boot/loader.conf`, save, reboot.

Comment: I have tried that , it only led to the system rebooting immidiately. Maybe this is because of the location of my file, or something like that.